# setting/using MAC that is multicast and local

Tags: network-interface, mac-address

is it possible to set a MAC address using `ifconfig` where it has a **11** in the least significant bits of the first octet?

For testing I want to do

```
ifconfig em1 hw ether 13ffffffffff
```

*using 12ffffffffff works*

At  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address  I can read about

- **unicast** or **multicast**
- **universally administered addresses (UAA)** or **locally administered addresses (LAA)**

I have a generic PC with the motherboard providing the one and only network port and the network cable is **unplugged** and this is on CentOS 7.6.

I can read the info at wikipedia on the matter but it doesn't actually help me.

- When/where/why does multicast and/or LAA apply?
- What is actually preventing `ifconfig hw ether` from succeeding on whatever linux OS and hardware when either of those bits have a 1?
- Is there something I can do to make `ifconfig em1 hw ether 13ffffffffff` work?

Comment: I don't know how to explain you that there's no meaning to a multicast source ethernet address. So I deleted my answer.

Comment: please retype that link you just had

Comment: [Multicast address - Ethernet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_address#Ethernet)

Comment: all physical MAC values of hardware are *source* MAC's.  Unicast is source mac to source mac.  **Will never find a *multicast* mac as a local *source* mac** therefore i'd bet `ifconfig` simply won't let it happen based on fundamental networking rules like only 0..F hex values.

Comment: Will only ever find multicast mac as the destination value in an outgoing packet... any receiving computer's data link layer recognizes it's a multicast MAC, strips it, passes datagram up to network layer to further process corresponding multicast IP address... IGMP...